# Google Sheets Query using important range and a dynamic cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a roster of students (Sheet 1) and I need a formula to search another sheet (Sheet 2) to see if each student on Sheet 1 is also on Sheet 2 and if they return the word "yes"/ if they are not I would like the cell to remain blank.

This is the formula I have:
`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1395p5J5oN4vYLPeyAdUQDZluwxWU53NYJPiqeHdXSEw/", "Quarter 3!A3:H"), "Select 'yes' where Col1="&$A7&"")`

The formula is not working properly.

For students that are on Sheet 2 the formula is returning two rows of data (two rows of "yes) and the first instance of "yes" include characters that I did not include in the query:
[image]

For students not on Sheet 2, the formula is returning a yes with the extra characters "yes"().

I feel like I should be using an IF function, but I could not get it to work with IMPORTRANGE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1395p5J5oN4vYLPeyAdUQDZluwxWU53NYJPiqeHdXSEw", "Quarter 3!A3:H"), 
 "select 'yes' where Col1="&$A7&"
  label 'yes''')
```

Comment: I just needed to add the last double quote. Thanks! `=iferror(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1395p5J5oN4vYLPeyAdUQDZluwxWU53NYJPiqeHdXSEw", "Quarter 3!A3:H"), 
 "select 'yes' where Col1="&$A7&"
  label 'yes'''"),"")`

Comment: Can you explain why the label clause fixed the issue?

Comment: @KelseyJimerson well when you do this in query you are creating a whole column of "yes" with a header row. that header row is your "yes" with empty () which indicates that column is not aggregated (sum,min,max,count,avg). to skip the creation of such redundant header row we need to use empty label for it